# Default widgets assignment - isn't working

Tags: widgets, sidebar

The question is regarding, calling the default widgets into the sidebar[s]:

So, despite the solution given in **[THIS THREAD](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35614/how-can-i-insert-default-widgets-when-my-theme-is-activated-similar-to-what-twe/35624)**, I tried a different way - Ian Stewart's borrowed solution given **[HERE](http://themeshaper.com/2009/07/06/wordpress-theme-sidebar-template/)**.

It's like, declaring the following lines into `functions.php`, suppose I have two different sidebars in my theme:

```
// Preset Widgets
$preset_widgets = array (
        'primary_widget_area'  => array( 'search', 'pages', 'categories', 'archives' ),
        'secondary_widget_area'  => array( 'links', 'meta' )
);

if ( isset( $_GET['activated'] ) ) {
        update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $preset_widgets );
}

//update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', NULL );




// Check for static widgets in widget-ready areas
function is_sidebar_active( $index ){

  global $wp_registered_sidebars;

  $widgetcolums = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

  if ($widgetcolums[$index]) return true;

        return false;

} // end is_sidebar_active
```

The problem is, my theme is NOT calling the default widgets in absence of any widgets at the beginning. I can't fix it, because I can't understand the code above and obviously the process explained by Ian Stewart.

And also, can't understand the explanation regarding `//update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', NULL );`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: [You solution may be here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757461/how-to-populate-widgets-on-sidebar-on-theme-activation)

Comment: Thanks @Ravs. It is't showing any fatal error when I've changed `is_sidebar_active()` into `is_active_sidebar()` in my `sidebar.php`. But switching from Twenty Twelve to my theme it's not showing the defaults widgets. I emptied the widget areas first in my theme, and then tried. Any other option?

Comment: I even used 'Theme Test Drive' plugin to see the default widget mode, it's not showing the defaults. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using a fallback with PHP conditionals: in my `sidebar.php` I coded like the following:

```
<?php if( is_active_sidebar('my_sidebar') ) { ?>

        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area">
            <ul class="xoxo">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar('my_sidebar'); ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->

<?php } else { ?>

        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area">
            <ul class="xoxo">

                <?php // Default Widget : Archives ?>
                <li id="default-widget-1" class="widget-container default-widgets">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'your-theme' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </li> <!-- #default-widget-1 -->

                <?php // Default Widget : Pages ?>
                <li id="default-widget-2" class="widget-container default-widgets">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Pages', 'your-theme' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='); ?>
                    </ul>
                </li> <!-- #default-widget-2 -->

                <?php // Default Widget : Categories ?>
                <li id="default-widget-3" class="widget-container default-widgets">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Categories', 'your-theme' ); ?></h3>                            
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_list_categories( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=' ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </li> <!-- #default-widget-3 -->

                <?php // Default Widget : Meta ?>
                <li id="default-widget-4" class="widget-container default-widgets">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'your-theme' ); ?></h3>                            
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_register(); ?>
                        <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                        <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                    </ul>
                </li> <!-- #default-widget-4 -->

            </ul> <!-- .xoxo -->

        </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->

<?php } //endif( is_active_sidebar ?>
```