# How do i place same widgets multiple time by default on theme activation?

Tags: theme-development, widgets, theme-options, activation

I am creating a portfolio theme and want to place some widgets on sidebar by default on theme activation. I did it but the problem is that, I want to place Text widget two times at the same sidebar say at primary sidebar but somehow my 2nd widget is not saved/ placed.

What should I do?

```
$sidebars_widgets = array();
$text = array();

$text[0] = array( "title"         =>    'Special Offers',
    "text"        =>    'Super Discount offers for everyone. <strong>25% Discount.</strong> Come, visit our Hotel at a special discounted rate.', );

$text[1] = array( "title"         =>    'Offers 2', 
"text"        =>    '25% Discount. Come, visit our Hotel at a special discounted rate.',   );

$text['_multiwidget'] = '1';

update_option( 'widget_text', $text );
$sidebars_widgets[ "primary-sidebar" ] = array("text-{$text[0]}","text-{$text[1]}");
update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets );
```

Comment: Can you show your code of displaying default widgets?

Comment: yeah sure. will paste it here

Comment: Question is edited

Answer (score 0):

You're quite off with your code. That's not how widgets are stored (at least not since 2.8), plus you're trying to inject arrays into strings!

Setting default widgets (at least in the admin) seems a complex & messy task. I would much rather opt for [default widgets in the display logic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/35614/1685) instead.

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-sidebar' ) ) : ?>

    <div class="widget">
        My default widgets!
    </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

The content within the `if` statement will print if no widgets have been configured, which will be the case on initial theme activation.

Comment: Ok. but this will call every time when primary-sidebar is empty and i want to do this only when theme is activate

Comment: Nothing "calls". It's simply placeholder content in your `sidebar.php`. A lot of authors do this!

Comment: Ok. so if i removed default widgets from sidebar then it will display default sidebar or it will not display?

Comment: and how do i call my default  widget inside div ? "My default widgets!".

Comment: If there are no widgets configured in your primary sidebar, then any HTML, PHP etc. inside that `if` will be displayed instead. I can't see how I can make it any clearer!

Comment: got it, but i don't want to display default widgets every time when no widgets are configured in primary sidebar.

Comment: Any alternative please!!!!!

Comment: As I mentioned, the alternative (storing them in the database) is pretty complicated, would have to investigate further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9352/discussion-between-shaikh-aezaz-and-thedeadmedic)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't exclusively dedicate my time just to you. I would suggest reading up on the WordPress codex, spend time "googling" for similar solutions, & be patient for others on WPSE to help out too :)

Comment: ok no problem but see what i want. 
I am creating theme auto install, i mean i provide one button or link to my client to do theme auto install. In theme auto install i will set basic theme options and menus and pages and posts etc.. with this setup i also want to set widgets as well.
The default widgets is comes up only when client clicked on Install sample data
if client clicked on delete sample data then it will remove
so i want another alternative